# Create distribution lists (mailing lists groups) using Google G Suite

Tags: active-directory, google-workspace, active-directory-group

I am wondering if it is possible to automatically create and populate distribution lists (mailing lists groups) from AD (Active directory) company field in AD user properties and using Google G Suite. If so, what are the steps I need to follow in Google G Suite?

Comment: What is what you need to get from Google G Suite Admin? The users? the groups? The organizational units?

Comment: @AndresDuarte I need to create automatically distribution lists based on an user AD field. For example, iterate over all AD Users and based on the company field I want to create  and populate the distribution list just created.